# django send email issue

Tags: python, django

I know there are similar questions to mine but my problem is weird.The email that I submit in the contact page doesn't get sent.Instead I get an email from my email.

here is what I did in settings.py:

```
              EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
              EMAIL_HOST_USER= 'my gmail adress'
              EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD= 'my password'
              EMAIL_PORT='587'
              EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
```

in views.py -contact

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    from django.conf import settings
    from .forms import contactForm
    # Create your views here.
    def contact(request):
        title = 'Contact Us'
        form = contactForm(request.POST or None)
        comfirm_message=None

        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']
            subject = 'Message from a user of Archives Manager'
            emailFrom = form.cleaned_data['email']

            message = '%s %s' % (comment, name)

            emailTo = [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
            send_mail(subject, message, emailFrom, emailTo, fail_silently=True)
            title = "Thanks!"
            comfirm_message='Thanks for the message. we will get right back to you.'
            form=None

        context = {'title': title, 'form' : form, 'comfirm_message': comfirm_message, }
        template = 'contact.html'
        return render(request,template,context)
```

and what I get in my gmail account is a message from my email adress not from the one I submited in EmailField()?

```
    from django import forms

    class contactForm(forms.Form):
        name = forms.CharField(required=False,max_length=100, help_text="100 is the maximum length" )
        email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
        comment = forms.CharField(required=True,widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Comment: I think what you want `emailTo = form.cleaned_data['email']` and then set `emailFrom = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER` instead. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Google is going to change the sender to your account. If tou want to send with other from address get your own mail server. But expect the mails to be filtered as SPAM oftenly.

Comment: Ok maybe because the app is less secured that emailFrom is changed to Email_HOST_USER